# Why are the templates requiring that I import jQuery in every template page, despite having it once in base.html?

Tags: django, django-templates

My base.html already includes jQuery. And my templates extend base, but won't allow the jquery to work unless I re-insert the script tag in each template. What's going on?

base.html:

```
...
{% block javascript %}
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
...  
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascript %}  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>  

I am required to place the script tag here again, despite having it in base.
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the javascript block in the other templates which means it will override the base javascript block so your jquery script should be in `base.html` body before the **Empty** javascript block, so something like this

`base.html`

```
<body>
   .....
   <!-- the bottom -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   {% block javascript %}
   {% endblock javascript %}
</body>
```

you can use `{{block.super}}` but the corrent method is the above :)

Answer (score 0):

Do in `details.html`

```
{% block javascript %}  
    {{ block.super }}
    <your jss>
{% endblock javascript %}
```